# Wicket Pom File errors

Tags: maven, wicket, pom.xml

I am trying to get started with a Wicket Quickstart. I am not very knowledgeable with a lot of the behind the scenes work from maven and the pom file. When I run my program I am getting:

7/7/14 6:19:41 PM CDT: Missing artifact org.apache.wicket:wicket:pom:6.15.0:compile
7/7/14 6:19:41 PM CDT: Missing artifact org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.6.4:compile

I am not sure what this means, or how to troubleshoot this. Here is a snippet of the areas that relate to the error:

```
<properties>
    <wicket.version>6.15.0</wicket.version>
    <jetty.version>7.4.0.v20110414</jetty.version>
    <log4j.version>1.2.16</log4j.version>
    <slf4j.version>1.6.1</slf4j.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>

    <!--  WICKET DEPENDENCIES -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.wicket</groupId>
        <artifactId>wicket</artifactId>
        <version>${wicket.version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.wicket</groupId>
        <artifactId>wicket-datetime</artifactId>
        <version>${wicket.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.wicket</groupId>
        <artifactId>wicket-extensions</artifactId>
        <version>${wicket.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.wicket</groupId>
        <artifactId>wicket-ioc</artifactId>
        <version>${wicket.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.wicket</groupId>
        <artifactId>wicket-spring</artifactId>
        <version>${wicket.version}</version>
    </dependency> 

    <!-- LOGGING DEPENDENCIES - LOG4J -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.16</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Where do I go from here?

Comment: I thought there was a Wicket archetype you could simply create? Are you following this ~ https://wicket.apache.org/start/quickstart.html ?

Comment: Yea, that's what this originated from. And we were getting those weird errors.. So we tried updating the Wicket version.

Comment: If possible you might want to change your slf4j.version to 1.6.4 to match it to the version referenced in the wicket pom. Maven should work out these collisions if the dependency isn't tagged as 'provided' in the wicket pom, which I can't check right now, but it shouldn't hurt to keep the numbers of different versions as small as possible.

Comment: I get these errors when I changed the slf4j version:

7/8/14 8:49:22 AM CDT: Missing artifact org.apache.wicket:wicket:pom:6.15.0:compile
7/8/14 8:49:22 AM CDT: Missing artifact org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.6.4:compile
7/8/14 8:49:22 AM CDT: Missing artifact org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.6.4:compile
7/8/14 8:49:22 AM CDT: Missing artifact org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.6.4:compile

Comment: In theory, these should have been downloaded by maven during `mvn install` or `mvn eclipse:eclipse`. Can you add the output of any of these?